# "[Network] undefined" when trying to use subscriber - URQL

Tags: graphql, apollo, subscriber, urql

I am trying to set up a subscriber to log some output on the creation of a new `Message`.

Currently using Urql, with ApolloServerExpress on the backend.

I am receiving an error from the `useSubscription` method which I am logging to the console :

```
message: "[Network] undefined"
name: "CombinedError"
```

I know for sure my backend is working as I can subscribe using the Graphiql playground just fine.
As far as front end goes, I have followed almost exactly as the example in the Urql docs.

WS Client:

```
const wsClient = createWSClient({
  url: "ws://localhost:4000/graphql",
});
```

Subscriber Exchange:

```
subscriptionExchange({
  forwardSubscription(operation) {
    return {
      subscribe: (sink) => {
        const dispose = wsClient.subscribe(operation, sink);
        return {
          unsubscribe: dispose,
        };
      },
    };
  },
}),
```

MessageList Component:

```
const newMessages = `
subscription Messages {
  newMessage {
    content
    status
    sender {
      id
      email
    }
    recipient {
      id
      email
    }
  }
}
`;
```

...

```
  const handleSub = (messages: any, newMessage: any) => {
    console.log("Messages: ", messages);
    console.log("newMessages: ", newMessage);
  };
  const [res] = useSubscription({ query: newMessages }, handleSub);

  console.log("Res: ", res);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up chalking `graphql-ws` and switched over to `subscriptions-transport-ws`.

Fixed my issues.

Comment: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` is no longer supported and refers to `graphql-ws`

Comment: I face the same problem using django with strawberry and urql - downgrading made it is not really an option. Maybe the `graphql-ws` implementation of your server is broken?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when using subscriptions with urql. In my case, I was able to do `console.log(error.networkError);` which gave a much more helpful error message than `[Network] undefined`.
You can read more about errors in urql [here](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/api/core/#combinederror).

The error I got from `error.networkError` was:

```
Event {
  "code": 4400,
  "isTrusted": false,
  "reason": "{\"server_error_msg\":\"4400: Connection initialization failed: Missing 'Authorization' or 'Cookie' header in JWT authenticati",
}
```

I was able to fix it by adding authentication to my subscription exchange setup. Here's the code I'm using now:

```js
const wsClient = createWSClient({
  url: "wss://your-api-url/graphql",
  connectionParams: async () => {
    // Change this line to however you get your auth token
    const token = await getTokenFromStorage();
    return {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };
  },
});
```